# Multiple object types in STL List, C++

Tags: c++, list, object, stl

So i have this type of inheritance:

```
Class A { virtual intfB(){} ; virtual intfC(){}; };
Class B : public A { int fB(){}; };
Class C : public A { int fC(){}; };
```

Then i have a class E that uses a list to store B and C objects.

```
Class E 
{
public:
    insert(A* obj){ l.push_front(obj);}
    print(){ /* uses iterator i to cout the fB() and fC() of the objects in l */ };

private:
    list <A*> l;
}
```

I set different functions of the `B` and `C` objects as `virtual` in `A` and then use an iterator i to access the l objects from within the `print()` function. My problem is that i cannot find a proper way to call `B::fB()` and `C::fC()` because the iterator can point to either a `C` or `B` object so i have to do something like this for each object that i don' t think is that practical:

```
cout << (*i) -> fB();
cout << (*i) -> fC();
```

So basicaly i call both `fC` and `fB` for every object regardless of type and the virtual function of the base class is called when it is not the correct object called.

This cannot be right tho, is it? How else can i achieve that?

On a side note should i use composition for classes E, C and B?

Comment: If you want to call one function on `B` and another on `C`, you've done something wrong in the design phase.

Comment: You seem to understand concept of virtual function so I'm not going to suggest `virtual int f()` which would be different for B and C, but you're probably looking for `((B*)(*i))->fB()`, aren't you?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to do. Assuming that i is of type std::list::iterator, then you should be able to call i->fB() and i->fC() on each object in the list and get the proper implementation (if it's a B object, you'll get B::fB, and A::fC, if it's a C object, you'll get A::fB and C::fC). If that's not what you want, then you shouldn't be putting them all in the same list, and possibly they shouldn't all descend from the same base.

Comment: Yeah i want to avoid calling A::fC if its a B object since it is not needed but i cannot find any way around it if i have to put the objects in the same std:list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct: Don't do it that way. If you want to print an item, call the function `print` in `A`, and override it in both child classes. Then you call `print` on each item as you iterate and each child does the right thing.

Comment: I think this is exactly what i was looking for but somehow i could not come up with that. Thanks for helping me unstuck ^^

Answer (score 0):

If intfB() and intfC() are technically the same function but with different implementations for B and C, then you should just declare one virtual function in A (perhaps called intf), and provide the necessary implementations for it in both B and C.

The idea of an abstract class is to define the base functionality that more detailed implementations of that class will share.  So with the above described scheme, every object pointed to by the elements of your list will be guaranteed to have a intf() implementation.

I'm not sure that your example will compile (I have not tested that though) because neither B nor C provide implementations for the virtual functions declared in A.

Comment: fB and fC have actually different implementations, they are unique for class B and class C respectively, i just have to declare them both in class A as virtual so i can call them from within the list using an iterator.